# Kibana 4 and relative time filter/json input

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

Currently trying to create a Kibana dashboard with realtime user information (current user count, where they are working etc) and I'm having trouble contraining a visulization timewise.

I've tried in a filter

```
@timestamp:[now-6M/M TO now]
```

and in the json input field

```
{
    "range" : {
         "@timestamp" : {
             "gte": "now-6d",
             "lte": "now" 
         }
     }
 }
```

[image]

However it is not working and I get the following error.

I have had this working previously, although different versions of Elasticseach1.6+ and Kibana4

I've tried to enable groovy scripting by adding

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

to the yml file, however it doesn't seem to be the problem. Any hints or is relative time ranges not possible anymore?

Error:

> Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed:
>   {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase
>   [query], all shards failed; shardFailures
>   {[bzqrC3gbSPi7fp0OWh81VQ][logstash-2015.02.14][0]:
>   SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.02.14][0]:
>   query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1437289456709 TO
>   1439881456710])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse
>   source
>   [{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":1437289456709,\"lte\":1439881456710}}}],\"must_not\":[]}}}},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"cardinality\":{\"field\":\"fields.UserName.raw\",\"range\":{\"timestamp\":{\"gte\":\"now-6d\",\"lte\":\"now\"}}}}}}]]];
>   nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.02.14][0]:
>   query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1437289456709 TO
>   1439881456710])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unexpected token
>   START_OBJECT in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSOHg.png).]];
>   }{[bzqrC3gbSPi7fp0OWh81VQ][logstash-2015.02.15][0]:
>   SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.02.15][0]:
>   query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1437289456709 TO
>   1439881456710])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse
>   source
>   [{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":.....................................................
>   at http://kibana:5601/index.js?_b=7489:43092:38
>       at Function.Promise.try (http://kibana:5601/index.js?_b=7489:46434:26)
>       at http://kibana:5601/index.js?_b=7489:46412:27
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at Function.Promise.map (http://kibana:5601/index.js?_b=7489:46411:30)
>       at callResponseHandlers (http://kibana:5601/index.js?_b=7489:43064:22)
>       at http://kibana:5601/index.js?_b=7489:43182:16
>       at wrappedCallback (http://kibana:5601/index.js?_b=7489:20893:81)
>       at wrappedCallback (http://kibana:5601/index.js?_b=7489:20893:81)
>       at http://kibana:5601/index.js?_b=7489:20979:26

Using Kibana 4.1.1 and Elasticsearch 1.7 on Windows 2012r2, jre 1.8.0.31

Answer (score 2):

You can use time range filter like:

```
timestamp:[now-6M/M TO now]
```

to get the data for the last 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see `SearchParseException` it means something's wrong with the syntax of your query. So it looks like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "",
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1437289456709,
                  "lte": 1439881456710
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "1": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "fields.UserName.raw",
        "range": {                         <------ HERE is the problem
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-6d",
            "lte": "now"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue lies in your `cardinality` aggregation, where you cannot have a `range` like that. It's almost certain that you're not inputting your `range` in the proper JSON field.

Why aren't you simply using the built-in time filter instead, you can achieve exactly what you want. Pick "Relative" and then "6 days ago" to NOW and you're done.

[image]

Comment: The visualization I'm creating is a metric, containing the current number of active users defined by logs by users within the last 10 minutes (Unique Count). The containing dashboard, will contain realtime stats like this (time contraint per visulization) but also stats where the user can use the build in time filter (e.g. there will be some counters for the day, week etc). So I can't solely rely on the buildin time filter, but need to scope the visualization.

Comment: I understand, but hard to tell without seeing your visualization/configuration, though. All I can tell is that your `range` is not pasted in the right place. if anything more you can share (screenshots, etc), it's welcome.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the visualization

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then, you can try to create a `filter` aggregation first, paste your `range` constraint in the JSON field and then add your current metric aggregation as a sub-aggregation of the `filter` aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for helping - I'm not sure understand your approach (new to Elasticsearch/Kibana) - Is this supposed to be possible in Kibana or is this a Elasticsearch query?